# Obtain YYYYMM String from Now in Delphi 4

Tags: delphi-4

I want to obtain an string 'YYYYMM' from `Now` procedure and from the month before the current one in Delphi 4.

For example: `202106` (Now) and `202105` (Now - 1)

How can afford that?

Comment: Do you mean YYYYMM? I think the function you need is DecodeDate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan right, already edited it, thank you!

Comment: OK, well you have the answer too

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've already read about DecodeDate but I can't figure out how to implement it to my requirement

Comment: Well, it tells you the year and month. I'm sure you can convert integers to strings. And then you just need to concatenate two strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DecodeDate` to split a TDateTime - like Now - into year, month and day parts. Then you can use `Format` to create the string with a 4 digits year and month as 2 digits with leading zeros:

```
var
    Year, Month, Day: Word;
    Today     : TDateTime;
    Yesterday : TDateTime;
    SToday     : String;
    SYesterday : String;
begin
    Today     := Now;
    Yesterday := Today - 1;

    DecodeDate(Today, Year, Month, Day);
    SToday := Format('%04d%02d', [Year, Month]);

    DecodeDate(Yesterday, Year, Month, Day);
    SYesterday := Format('%04d%02d', [Year, Month]);
end;
```